# React Send Target Along with OnClick Event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two Popper elements of Material UI, they are supposed to open up different menus. How can I have only 1 Display function like this to make both Popper elements open and close independently? I was trying to give one popper `target="appUI"` and other `target="userUI"` so then through `event.target.target` I would be able to figure out which one they clicked and show that popper but I couldn't get it to work..

```
  popperDisplay = event => {
    console.log(event.target)
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    this.setState(state => ({
      anchorEl: currentTarget,
      userUI: !state.userUI,
    }));
  };
```

Below is the sample project I created to display the issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/k28o1lxw43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id of the element you are calling from
 `popperDisplay(event, id)` to distinguish elements.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1qrn61q2y3?fontsize=14

You'll have access to the id in the display().

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to send in exact name so I don't have if/else statements? ie `onClick={(e) => this.popperDisplay(e, "appsUI")}`

Comment: Yeah sure, you can use whatever id you want.

Comment: Just make sure to use that id to update the state in the display function.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it worked for you, it'll be helpful for others to know :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I just did = )

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the event through wherever you're passing the `onClick` handler like this:

```
<button onClick={event => this.popperDisplay(event)} />
```